# How to resolve the Error opening directory '/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied error in Disk Usage Analyzer?

Tags: permissions, filesystem

- Is this a normal warning?
- Can it be safely ignored?
- Does it require any action from the user?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK. Some directories do not have permissions to list the content for a non-root user.

These directories usually are not large and that "problem" does not seriously affect the result of the scan.

You can ignore it safely.

If you really suspect that something is wrong in this directory in terms of disk usage, you can look into it by

```
sudo ls -l /etc/cups/ssl
```

It should have only two symlinks there.

Comment: Thank you! I am assuming [this output](http://i.imgur.com/8Xy2jaY.png) is correct then. :-)